# Inappropraite usage of AOP

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj

What are bad practices of using AOP?
I mean do we have situations when AOP is inappropriate to use.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, AOP is a *too* powerfull tool. With AOP you can change so many things that it can become very hard to maintain and debug the code.

I recommend to limit the use of AOP as much as possible.

There are also some less powerfull versions of AOP, such as EJB Interceptors, which are often enough to do some cross-cutting concerns or monitoring.

Comment: I think that's sound reasoning. Personally, I try to limit my AOP-usage to only apply it to (custom) annotations. That way, it's clear when an advice is applied.

Answer (score 0):

We will avoid the AOP in the following cases

Don't want to provide the enterprise business/Service.

Declarative Transaction Management..

Conditional Aspects based up on your own criteria's...............